# PHPUnit: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, docker, phpunit

I've been at this for a while now and I still don't know exactly what I might have missed here.
I have php-fpm and mysql on separate docker containers and I can access data from the database without any issue on my Symfony project except for when I try to run tests via PHPUnit in which the tests that require a connection to the database keep returning this error: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Below is how I've set up the phpunit.xml file

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" executionOrder="depends,defects" forceCoversAnnotation="false" beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true" beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true" beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true" verbose="true">
  <coverage>
    <include>
      <directory>src/</directory>
    </include>
  </coverage>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <directory>test/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="integration">
      <directory>test/Integration</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <logging>
    <testdoxHtml outputFile="phpunit/testdox.html"/>
    <testdoxText outputFile="phpunit/testdox.txt"/>
  </logging>
  <php>
    <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/proj_db?serverVersion=5.7" force="true"/>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="dev" force="true"/>
    <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" force="true"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

I've even tried to use the address given by `SELECT user()` for the database in which I get `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out` instead.

Do I have to allow the connection separately from the normal project?

EDIT: I connect to the database in code this way

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
```

And the information from the connection returns this:

```
/home/user/docs/project/src/src/Proj/Infrastructure/Doctrine/Repository/RequestRepository.php:155:
array(11) {
  'driver' => string(9) "pdo_mysql"
  'url' => string(60) "mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/proj_db?serverVersion=5.7"
  'host' => string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  'port' => string(4) "3306"
  'user' => string(4) "root"
  'password' => string(8) "password"
  'driverOptions' =>
  array(0) {
  }
  'serverVersion' => string(3) "5.7"
  'defaultTableOptions' =>
  array(1) {
    'collate' => string(18) "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
  }
  'dbname' => string(5) "proj_db"
  'charset' =>
  string(7) "utf8mb4"
}
```

Comment: You would normally have the database information split into the parts, how do you connect to the database (can you show your code).

Comment: You will have to change the database url hostname from localhost if the app is running as a docker container,

Comment: @sachin is this the ip address of the mysql container found in `docker network inspect`? Or is there somewhere else i should be looking for this information?

Comment: @user3249400 Instead of localhost ip, try specifying the container name of the mysql container.

Comment: @sachin - using the mysql container worked for me - thanks